# Class not outputting

Tags: php, oop

I have a simple class that is not outputting:

```
class ICRR extends Profile {
    public $recommendation_text;
    public $comments;
    public $men_id;
    public $recommendation;
    public $uid;

    public function __construct($uid)
    {   
        include 'con.php';  

        $stmt = $conn->prepare(
            'SELECT * FROM icrr WHERE uid = :uid');
        $stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this->men_id = $row['men_id'];
            $this->uid = $row['uid'];
            $this->nid = $row['nid'];
            $this->recommendation = $row['reccomendation'];
            $this->comments = $row['comments'];
            $this->date_submitted = $row['date_submitted'];
        }
    }

    public function recommendation_text() {
        switch ($this->recommendation){
            case 1 :
                $this->recommendation = 'Yes Certify';
            break;
            case 2 :
                $this->recommendation = 'No Do Not Certify';
            break;
            case 3 :
                $this->recommendation = 'Certify Pending Requirements';
            break;

            default : echo "Recommendation Not Received";
        }
        return $this->recommendation_text;
    }
}
```

When I ask:

```
$ICRR = new ICRR($uid);
var_export($ICRR);
```

Everything is null.  I checked the query and it is returning the data fine... I used a class like this before and it worked fine so I think I am missing something I just cant see..

Comment: are you passing a valid value for $uid when you create the object of the class ?

Comment: Yes:

$ICRR = new ICRR($uid); 

and when I ask for var_dump($row) I get results...

Comment: Hi Maximus...
thanks for the reply... it turns out it was working I was just hitting a record with no results

Sorry to waste your time :(

Comment: Do anyone know how I can close or delete this?